# Selection of a set of combinations that encompass all unique elements

Tags: r, matrix, combinatorics

## Objective

I am trying to select a set of combinations, which encompass a set of unique elements (`inbreds`). The ultimate purpose is the setup of a design matrix for microarray data. In the column of `combi_mat` I have the unique names of all lines (`inbreds`), which were used. In the rows I have the arrays with the corresponding names of combinations between some of the lines from the columns.

### Dummy Data

The design matrix for all combinations is build as follows:

```
### Function for the setup of a design matrix.
expand.grid.unique <- function(x, y, include.equals = FALSE) {
x <- unique(x)
y <- unique(y)
g <- function(i) {
    z <- setdiff(y, x[seq_len(i - include.equals)])
    if (length(z)) cbind(x[i], z, deparse.level = 0)
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(x), g))
}

### Unique inbred lines.
inbreds <- c("F001", "F002", "F003", "F004", "F005", "P001", "P002", "P003")

### Create arrays (i.e. hybridization pairs).
hybrids <- expand.grid.unique(inbreds, inbreds)
hybrids <- paste0(hybrids[, 1], ".", hybrids[, 2])

### When an inbred line is an element of an array (`hybrids`), assign 
### `1` to the corresponding cell.
comb_mat <- matrix(0, nrow = length(hybrids), ncol = length(inbreds),
                   dimnames = list(hybrids, inbreds))
splnames <- gsub(pattern = "[.]", replacement = "|", x = rownames(comb_mat))
for (i in seq_len(nrow(comb_mat))) {
comb_mat[i, grep(splnames[i], colnames(comb_mat))] <- 1
}
```

### Constraints

My goal is the selection of rows in `comb_mat` that are subject to the following constraints:

1. Each column name must be present in the final set of arrays.
2. The size of the final set of arrays must be one less than the number of columns.

In order to satisfy both conditions, I define a vector `fin_count` which specifies that two elements of `inbreds` can only occur once (head and tail of the chain of combinations) whereas all other elements must occur twice (chain links that overlap).

```
fin_count <- c(1, 1, rep(2, times = length(inbreds) - 2))
```

### My Current Approach

I test for the above condition, by selecting `length(inbreds) - 1` rows (condition 2) and checking for the frequency of elements in the selected arrays via `fin_count` (condition 1):

```
repeat {
rand_design <- comb_mat[sample(seq_len(nrow(comb_mat)),
                                size = length(inbreds) - 1), ]
if (all(colSums(rand_design) %in% fin_count)) break
}
```

The output of this small example would be the following, where the column names represent unique arrays that encompass all inbred lines in the rows:

```
          F001 F002 F003 F004 F005 P001 P002 P003
F001.P001    1    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
F004.P002    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
F003.P003    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
F002.P001    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0
F004.F005    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
F003.F005    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
F002.P002    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

### How to Optimize the Above Code?

The problem is that this approach merely works for small sets of lines and hybridization pairs. In reality I have up to 103 unique inbred lines and up to 400 hybridization pairs from which I must choose. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this code? I have previously considered the use of `expand.grid()` but this does not seem to be an option for so many combinations.